# How to register class as interface but invoke a method?

Tags: c#, lambda, autofac

Following [this](https://piotrgankiewicz.com/2016/06/06/storing-c-app-settings-with-json/) blog I have copied the code below and it works fine, but I have modified it to suit my needs by creating an interface for `DatabaseSettings` and `UserSettings` with the same suffix by adding I to the current name. But the issue is that it is trying to register the interface as an interface which is wrong?

Before making the changes `settings` variables only have two entries now that I have added the interfaces `settings` is picking up the interface (because of the suffix) so it now has for entries instead of adding them as entries I would like to use them with the corresponding class and still invoke `.LoadSection(type)`

```
public class SettingsModule : Module
{
    private readonly string _configurationFilePath;
    private readonly string _sectionNameSuffix;

    public AeSettingsModule(string configurationFilePath, string sectionNameSuffix = "Settings")
    {
        _configurationFilePath = configurationFilePath;
        _sectionNameSuffix = sectionNameSuffix;
    }

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {

        var settings = Assembly.Load(nameof(DataLayer))
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith(_sectionNameSuffix, StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
            .ToList();

         settings.ForEach(type =>
         {
             builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<ISettingsReader>().LoadSection(type))
             .As(type)
             .SingleInstance();
         });
    }
}
```

```
public class DatabaseSettings: IDatabaseSettings
{
    public string ConnectionString { get;  set; }
    public int TimeoutSeconds { get; set; }
}

public interface IDatabaseSettings
{
    string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    int TimeoutSeconds { get; set; }
}
```

The error message I am getting is:

```
`System.MissingMethodException: 'Cannot create an instance of an interface.'`
```

Because I have changed the `Constructor injection from a class to an interface:

```
public UserService(IDatabaseSettings databaseSettings, IUserSettings userSettings)
{
    ...
}
```

Because I have added the interfaces and it has the same prefixes "Settings" it is picking up the interfaces which I don't wan, instead I would like to use it with the corresponding class?

I am trying to do this(but with the syntax above because I would like to invoke `LoadSection` too):

`builder.RegisterType<DatabaseSettings>().As<IDatabaseSettings>();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution through trial and error and the app works as expected but what I am not sure of is if it efficient, reliable etc.

I am posting merely to get feedback and if it is valid other might be able to use it.

```
var settings = Assembly.Load(nameof(DataLayer))
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith(_sectionNameSuffix, StringComparison.InvariantCulture ) && !t.IsInterface)
    .ToList();

    settings.ForEach(type =>
    {
        builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<ISettingsReader>().LoadSection(type))
            .As(type.GetInterfaces())
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    });
```